# js syntax errors in text adventure

Tags: javascript, syntax

hi i'm new to java script and I wrote a text adventure for a school project and I keep getting these error when I try to run it

```
js: "adventure.js", line 4: missing ( before condition
js: if var start = "turn on lights" || "light switch" 
js: ......^
js: "adventure.js", line 7: missing ( before condition
js: if var start = "open window" || "window"
js: ......^
js: "adventure.js", line 10: missing ( before condition
js: if var start = "wait"
js: ......^
js: "adventure.js", line 13: missing ( before condition
js: if var start = "opendoor"
js: ......^
js: "adventure.js", line 18: missing ( before condition
js: if secoundAct = "open left door" || "open door left" || "left door" || "   enter left door"
js: .............^
js: "adventure.js", line 21: missing ( before condition
js: if secoundAct = "open right" || "enter right" || "enter right door"|| "open right door"
js: .............^
js: "adventure.js", line 24: missing ( before condition
js: if secoundAct = "go back" || "turn around"
js: .............^
js: "adventure.js", line 29: missing ( before condition
js: if thirdAct = "go back" || "turn back"
js: ...........^
js: "adventure.js", line 32: missing ( before condition
js: if thirdAct = "go down right stairs" || "go right" || "right" || "down right" || "down left" || "go left" || "go down left stairs" || "jump over balcony" || "hop over balcony" 
js: ...........^
js: "adventure.js", line 37: missing ( before condition
js: if fourthAct = "monster lodging" || "go into monster lodging" || "go into giant death monnster lodging" 
js: ............^
js: "adventure.js", line 40: missing ( before condition
js: if fourthAct = "go into escape pods" || "escape pods" 
js: ............^
js: "adventure.js", line 1: Compilation produced 11 syntax errors.
```

does anyone know what im doing wrong 
bellow the code if it helps https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz_LEt8rxihuNGdUUUluelRhQ1E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you looked at, read, and considered what each error message means?  The [if else language refrence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this statement

```
if var start = "turn on lights" || "light switch"
```

1. You're declaring the variable by using var. You don't need this.
2. If you're trying to do an equality check, use ===. As written the expression is trying to **assign** "turn on lights" OR (the double pipe ||) to a var start. This doesn't make sense - the expression will always evaluate true.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators to see why. "turn on the lights" is not null or an empty string, so is true. The same applies to "light switch". In the example above

```
"turn on lights" || "light switch"
```

will always be true.

1. The error messages tell you a lot of what you need. They are saying that they expected to see a `(` . Enclose your condition in parentheses.

So the net of all this, your statements should read something like

```
if(start === "turn on lights" || start === "light switch"){
  // do something
}
```

Note that you need to say `start ===` on either side of the OR, you can't shortcut this.